# codeigniter value type from db

Tags: database, string, codeigniter, types

I have some values in my db (type string: ex id: 0001) but when I fetch data, CI convert it to int and I get 1 as result. How to avoid it? I want to display the db's value 0001 in the front

Comment: if you use mysql then you can use LPAD(id,4,'0') in select query

Comment: :) I'm knew with CI, can you help me how to do this?

Comment: yes, I use mysql with wamp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

Model

```
function getValues(){

    $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
    $result = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $id = str_pad($row->id, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $result[$id] = $row->type;
    }

    return $result;

}
```

Controller

```
$result = $this->model_var->getValues();
$data['result'] = $result;
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

View

```
foreach($result as $key => $val) {
    echo 'key: ' . $key . ', value: ' . $val;
}
```

Comment: It works, but when I get the result ($data) with angularjs I have the same probleme.

Comment: your motivation was to get the '0' padded value and I did it for you but I do not know angular js. You also did not mentione in the question that you need it in angular js. Please mark it as answer.